# Buttons displaying through a popup container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, popup

I have a multiple functional Javascript popup buttons. When the popup appears, however, the buttons after the one clicked appear on top of the popup container, and the previous buttons appear behind the container. How do I make it so the popup container displays through all the buttons once it appears? The HTML div is repeated 4 times.

```js
//Popup
function open() {
  document.querySelectorAll(".button a").forEach((a) => {
    a.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("active");
  });
  this.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add("active");
  //popup is sibling of a's parent element 
}

function close() {
  this.parentElement.classList.remove("active"); // .popup
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 2em 2em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 340px);
  grid-gap: 55px;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 170px;
  position: relative;
}

.popup {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 50px;
  background: #A6A6A6;
}

.active {
  display: block;
  top: 45%;
  visibility: visible;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <br>
  <div class="box button">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Lorem Ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="popup">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <video src="video.mov" controls></video>
    <p>
      Insert Text Here
    </p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="border: 2px solid; padding: 5px;">CLOSE</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please make the snippet we made into a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS

```
.popup{
  z-index:99999;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what z-index does in this case?

Comment: It basicly represents the depth into the page. You can think that the page is made from more layers overlapped. You're elements were on the same z-index so, the element that poped out was the last element written into the html code. You can take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index